# How to return 404 with asp.net mvc view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

How  do I achieve the below functionality?

**My controler**:

```
if (something == null)
{         
     //return the view with 404 http header
     return View();          
}

  //return the view with 200 http header
  return View();
```

Comment: Returning the view with a 404 make no sense. 404 is the status code for page not found. To also return a page is just plain strange. Expect browser inconsistencies if you do this.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just write

```
Response.StatusCode = 404;
```

before returning the view.

Comment: This is exactly what `return HttpNotFound();` does under the covers. It adds a 404 StatusCode and StatusDescription to the current HttpContext Response.

Comment: @levelnis The difference is that this command does not end the function like `return`. By the way: Alan Low's answer is exactly the same as mine, and there might be a reason for it being upvoted...

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  For this to actually suit my needs, I had to add the following to my web config: <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>

Answer (score 17):

```
if (something == null)
{         
   return new HttpNotFoundResult(); // 404
}
else
{
   return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK); // 200
}
```

Comment: The question is not how to return 404, but how to return the same page with 404 http header.

Comment: If you think about it, every request to a web server simply returns a response with a status code. If the status code is 200 there's usually some html with it which we think of as a page, but it's just a status code as far as the server is concerned, whether that's 200, 404, etc.

Comment: FYI `new EmptyResult()` is the same as `new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK)`

Answer (score 10):

```
if (something == null)
{         
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    return View();          
}

//return the view with 200 http header
return View();
```

Comment: So, why the first `return`, since the second will return as well.

Comment: In this example as is, I agree, only the last return would be needed. However I've made an assumption that there might have been some additional code after the null check which would only be relevant if 'something' wasn't null.

Comment: As I've [stated on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764685/how-to-return-404-with-asp-net-mvc-view#comment80368073_13764685) returning a view and a 404 is bizarre behaviour. I would not recommend doing this (even if the OP asked for it)

Answer (score 9):

You should set `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` property of `Response` as `true`.

```
public ActionResult NotFound()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Best answer for my scenario as it allows you to return an arbitrary view instead of the server taking over and displaying the default 404 response

Answer (score 2):

```
if (something == null)
{         
   return HttpNotFound();
}

return View();
```

Comment: As with the above, you'll note that the View is not returned here.

Answer (score 1):

I would throw a 404 exception and create a custom exception filter that return a not found page for 404 errors. The built-in `HandleError` filter doesn't handle 404 errors.

```
if (something == null)
{         
   throw new HttpException(404, "Not found")
}

return View();
```