# ASP.NET 4.0 How to return a 401 with a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

All I want to do is when a user fails to login correctly, my controller picks this us and sends the user back to the login view in the controller with a message that their log in has failed and they should try again. However, I have some scripts that also use this system, and it would be very helpful to them if this returned a 401.Unfortunately setting a Response.StatusCode=401; at the end just before I return the ActionResult doesn't work.

I'm not using any form of windows authentication, I need authenticate against an Active Directory server from mono. I'm developing on windows, but deploying on Linux/mono.

tl;dr Return page with a user defined status code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return 404 with asp.net mvc view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764685/how-to-return-404-with-asp-net-mvc-view)

Comment: "...this returned a 404.Unfortunately setting a Response.StatusCode=401;..." so do you want "not found" or "Unauthorized"?

Comment: Unauthorized. I made a mistake when writing the question, apologies

Comment: I've tried to adapt some of the solutions from the question suggested, but nothing worked.