# How can I return 404 page view in controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

My project has a 404 page already. I set it by the `app.UseStatusCodePages()` in `startup.cs` and it works well.

Now I have a controller:

```
[Route("{id:int}.html")]
public IActionResult Test(int id)
{
      var A=///some logic;
      if(A!=null)
      {
       return View(A);
      }
      else
      {
       return NotFound();
      }
}
```

Well, if the A is null, the browser only returns a `This localhost page can’t be found` page while not the 404 pages.

I don't want to use something redirect method, for it will return a 302 code while not only a 404 code.

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could specify the path to your 404 page when returning a `View`.

e.g. `return View("~/Views/Error/404.cshtml");`

If you want to use it multiple times, I would suggest putting it in a function in a base class.

```
protected IActionResult 404View() {
    return View("~/Views/Error/404.cshtml");
}
```

---

`NotFound` returns a status code rather than a view, as explained in the summary

> Creates an Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NotFoundResult that produces a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status404NotFound

---

If you want to return a 404 status code and a View, you can just set the status code on the response before returning the View as described in [How to return 404 with asp.net mvc view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13764873/3688864).

```
Response.StatusCode = 404;
return View("~/Views/Error/404.cshtml");
```

Comment: This way returns the page successfully while it returns a 200 status code, not a 404 status code.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want. A 404 status code tells the browser that the page was not found.

Comment: Apparently you can do `Response.StatusCode = 404;` before returning the View [How to return 404 with asp.net mvc view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13764685/3688864)